# Handling Nextjs pages and API update

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have a website made in Nextjs with also some custom API. I also have an Apollo Server running for graphql. My question is more focused on NextJS, but I have the same doubts about any kind of services that running online.

When I need to change a small portion of code of my API or change some CSS files or just some js line of my website, everytime I need to re-build the project, stop the Next.js service and start it again. So:

- It's not better if I use another server that handle only the API (perhaps a basic node server), so, when I want to do some small fix on the API I don't need to re-build (and then stop) the entire site?
- How I can avoid to block my website anytime I need to change something?

Comment: using docker will help.

Comment: How? In any case NextJS needs to re-build and re-start.

Comment: when you build your app with docker, it creates new container and all build files will be allocated there only thus no effect on working/existing container (even if new build fails). Also docker will replace working container with new one only if new build was successful.  Added bonus is it caches build steps, which will improve build time significantly.

Comment: I have deployed nextjs app without docker before (I didn't knew docker at that time) and it was really terrible experience.